# How can I get Safari to set kMDItemWhereFroms when using "Save Image to Downloads"?

Tags: macos, safari, metadata

Specifically in Safari 9.0: when I save an image via right clicking and selecting *Save image as...* I can specify the downloads folder and the kMDItemWhereFrom data is saved just fine, as revealed both by selecting the file in Finder and using <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and also via Terminal using `mdls`.

However, when I save an image via right clicking *Save Image to "Downloads"* the kMDItemWhereFrom data *isn't* saved. This occurs even when selecting exactly the same image. I'm pretty sure it did work back in previous versions of Safari, as I have older images saved that have this data.

I can't find any documentation referring to this change. Is there a way to restore the functionality? It was far more convenient before.

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity [to file a bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: @patrix Same issue occurs with OSX 10.8/Safari 6.0. Perhaps I am mistaken and it's *never* been saved with *Save Image to "Downloads"*, or else a change occurred prior to Safari 6. Looking at my older images, it looks like the 'where from' data was dropped from them around January 2012, which suggests Safari 5.

Comment: On macOS 11 Big Sur `kMDItemWhereFroms` is only saved when saving an image from a website via drag-n-drop from Safari to Finder. It is indeed a bug that the routine to write `kMDItemWhereFroms` seems to be tied to a particular user event instead of the asset saving routine always writing out `kMDItemWhereFroms` regardless which user event triggers the asset saving routine.

Answer (score -1):

[SafariStand](https://github.com/anakinsk/SafariStand/) (a SIMBL plugin for Safari) can fix this if you're running Safari 11 or earlier. It hasn't been updated in a while presumably because everyone who tries eventually gets tired of Apple breaking things.